# How to I get a TM with lowest index?

Tags: terminology, turing-machines

I'm struggling to understand this question:

> Give an encoding of the Turing machine with lowest index that accepts anything but the empty set.

I know what an encoding of a Turing Machine is. But my professor didn't explain what the index of a Turing machine is and how I know that it is lower or higher? Can someone explain what lowest index is and how would I go about this problem?

Comment: An index and an encoding are the same concept, only the encoding could be a string, and the index is a natural number representing that string.

Comment: This question can not be answered from the information you give us. The answer depends on a) which TM encoding one uses and b) how to order encodings (if encodings are not numbers, in which case we'd use $\leq$ by default).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then it simply asks for the TM with the encoding who is ordered first in the lexicographic ordering.

As you surely know, many TMs perform the same task.
Look at all the TMs that accept anything but empty set. Look at the encodings of all of those. Each encoding is simply a string. If you write all those string ordered using the lexicographical ordering (like in the dictionary), which string comes first? That should be your answer.

Comment: I have a professor who doesn't explain the material very well. How would I know from the encoding that machine accepts anything but the empty set?

Comment: The encoding describes the "internals" of the TM: how many states it has, which states are final, the transition function, etc. To see how it can be done (unless you saw it in class), you should probably check a textbook.